# Use postgres Pgtap with logical operators

Tags: sql, postgresql, supabase, pgtap

I am testing my supabase table using pgtap and [supabase test helpers](https://github.com/usebasejump/supabase-test-helpers)

I have a table `posts` with a `creator` uuid and a `published` boolean field. My row level policy checks that creators of a post are always allowed to see it, regardless if published or not. Anonymous users are only allowed to see a post when it has been published. This works as intended.

How can I test this behavior with pgtap? I tried using `is()`, but this allows me only to check for one of the two constraints and not combine both using `OR`.

I would need something like: `is(creator, tests.get_supabase_uid('test_owner') -> 'id') OR is(published, true) FROM posts`

Answer (score 0):

There is a 3rd party guide available for testing supabase RLS policies [here](https://usebasejump.com/blog/testing-on-supabase-with-pgtap)

Check out the section "Testing your RLS Policies"

It references [supabase-test-helpers](https://github.com/usebasejump/supabase-test-helpers) but you can copy out the functions you need if you'd prefer not to use it.